# AddFront in LinkedList with tail and reference to previous node from the tail (tail.Previous)

Tags: c#, algorithm, doubly-linked-list

Could you please help to understand, how I can modify AddFront method in LinkedList and set a tail and reference to the previous node (for example tail.Previous)? The tail should point out the first added element (last element in the LinkedList) and tail.Previous to second added element (second element from the end) and be able to access elements from tail to the head using Previous property.
Thanks.

```
public class Node
{
public int Data;
public Node Next;
public Node Previous;

public Node(int x)
{
    Data = x;
    Next = null;
    Previous = null;
}

public class MyLinkedList
{
    private int Length { get; set; }
    private Node head = null;
    private Node tail = null;

    public void AddFront(int x)
    {
        var newNode = new Node(x);
        newNode.Next = head;
        if (head != null)
        {
            head.Previous = newNode;
        }
        //Somewhere here tail and tail.Previous should be set

        head = newNode;

        Length++;
    }
}
```

Comment: "//Somewhere here tail and tail.Previous should be set", only if tail is null....

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `else` case:

```
    if (head != null)
    {
        head.Previous = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        tail = newNode;
    }
```